# Rails post on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a bit confusing on this: Can i do a post and put action using the Member in Routes on the same edit page?

To be More Clear:

**Routes**

```
resources :users  do 
    member do
      post  'edit'
    end
  end
```

**Will Generate**

```
edit_user POST       /users/:id/edit(.:format)                             users#edit
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
resources :users  do 
    member do
      match 'edit' , via: [:get, :post]
    end
end
```

This gives me

```
$ rake routes | grep 'edit'
                             edit_user GET|POST /users/:id/edit(.:format)    
                             {:action=>"edit_get_post", :controller=>"users"}
```